# Difference between SDO_CONTAINS and SDO_RELATE with MASK=CONTAINS?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, oracle-spatial

What is the difference between following oracle spatial query? Does both function return same result? I am confused with `MASK=CONTAINS`

```
SDO_CONTAINS (col1_geometry,col2_geometry )='TRUE'
SDO_RELATE (col1_geometry,col2_geometry ,'MASK=CONTAINS')='TRUE'
```

Comment: Have you tried running them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are exactly the same. SDO_CONTAINS is just simpler to write.